# WiFi dies if phone tries to connect to it

Tags: wi-fi

### The basic situation is this:

- Phone tries to connect to my parents' WiFi, fails

  - The WiFi then drops shortly, no other devices can connect to it
  - A laptop connected via ethernet to the router can still access the internet
- Only way to resolve WiFi issue is to restart the router.
- Connecting to another WiFi (i.e. my dad's phone's hotspot) also fails, no connection can be made

### I have tried the following things:

#### On my phone:

- Factory reset (running the latest pre-Oreo OxygenOS, OnePlus 5)
- Restore an old backup from a month ago, full NANDROID via TWRP.
- Wipe everything, again.
- The above, with various combinations of...

  - Locked or unlocked bootloader
  - Stock recovery or TWRP
- Flashing the latest LineageOS nightly.

None of the above attempts changed anything. Even during the initial setup process, trying to connect to the WiFi fails (and kills the WiFi for everyone else)

#### On the router

- Factory reset
- Changing from DHCP to static IP (some forum posts suggest duplicate IP in this scenario)
- Changing the address range of DHCP from .100 - .199 to .10 - .99 to ensure all devices get new IPs

### Conclusion

I have googled all the things. I have tried everything I can think of. I have no idea what else to try.
On top of this, the mobile network at my parents' place is so bad my phone basically has no internet connectivity.
This has been going on for 3 days now.
I am sad.

Comment: The main problem is clearly the router. The WiFi should never drop. When encountering such problems you should name the router and firmware version so that other users are warned...

Comment: As I wrote in the post, I also could not connect to _other_ WiFis, e.g. mobile hotspots, so the router could not have been the primary issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigh...

I wiped everything and installed the OxygenOS Oreo beta through adb sideload and now it works.

Hell do I know why this works now, but not even a complete OS switch to LineageOS worked.

Comment: I had a similar issue but caused by my new laptop. Turns out it was the outdated router's firmware issue. The firmware might be old and contain bugs when interacting with newer WiFi devices, make sure you have the latest firmware installed on your router or simply upgrade if it has become too old.